# receive a video file with a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, wireless, microprocessor, video-transmitter

I want to send a video stream to a microcontroller via wifi. what microcontroller choose for this task?
-Must take into account that the video will be transmitted through a phone
-The video will be in different format and larger format will be HD (1920 * 1080)
-The video is intended to be displayed on a TV screen
-The video will be played at the same time it is to be sent to crotch... 
I work on a project to read streaming a video that is in the phone by a plasma tv...
 I had my start and I still looking for landmarks

Comment: 1920x1080x24bit @ 60FPS has a raw bit rate of 3Gbps. How on earth do you expect a tiny microcontroller to receive that much data and send it out to a PC? This question has been asked many times before with the same answer, no you can't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transmitting a video stream through a microcontroller](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/48986/transmitting-a-video-stream-through-a-microcontroller)

Comment: Chances are you want at least a small system-on-module or embedded board with megabytes of SDRAM, either to buffer and pass on a compressed stream, or else to decompress and render it and drive an HDMI, RGB, or whatever interface.  Look at the parts usually used in set-top-box applications, or those found in android tablets with video out.

Comment: Also duplicate of [Transmitting a video stream through a microcontroller's wifi](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49045/transmitting-a-video-stream-through-a-microcontrollers-wifi?rq=1)

Comment: the microcontroller does not generate or process the video but will just pass it to the tv

Comment: What microprocessor for example?

Comment: the raspberry pi 2 go?

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic in this forum and will be closed.  Reference: Help->Tour->Don't ask about...Shopping or buying recommendations.

Comment: by what means can I send videos to the TV

Answer (score 1):

Microcontrollers, are designed for simple tasks, they can not do any thing any where near video, what you need is a microprocessor, that is capable of processing video.

Comment: What microprocessor for example?

Comment: the microcontroller does not generate or process the video but will just pass it to the tv

Comment: TV's don't generally accept video in microcontroller-friendly formats

Comment: Sorry, I went to walk my dog. Currently looking for one now. Will update when I find one.

Comment: the raspberry pi 2 go?

Comment: by what means can I send videos to the TV

Comment: @wahab: perhaps you should make a list of devices that send videos to TVs, and then try to understand what makes them tick.

Comment: I agree with  uint128_t on that  one, Very good idea!